# Several Warnings on CKFinder

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor, ckfinder

Today I recieved the question from one of our clients that they could not use the ckfinder any more. When checking I recieve these warnings:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /***/***/domains/***.***/public_html/ckfinder/core/connector/php/php5/Utils/Security.php on line 72

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /***/***/domains/***.***/public_html/ckfinder/core/connector/php/php5/Utils/Security.php on line 72

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /**/***/domains/***.***/public_html/ckfinder/config.php on line 2
```

The first 2 messages are repeated about 10 times then the last one in showing.
To my knowledge and the edit dates I see on the FTP there has not been a change in the files for atleast a year. It has worked without these warnings untill a couple of weeks ago.

What would cause these warnings and how could I fix them.

Kind regards,

Martijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the error suggests that you are using a modified version of CKFinder as the original code does not have any references to `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Unless you store files in a database or log actions to the database, this code might not be needed at all.

Comment: As you stated that it a modified version, we went for a fresh install, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This (most probably) hasn't anything to do with ckeditor but with your app config / php setup.

Check your database connection / credentials and wether you use `mysql_real_escape_string()` somewhere before actually having a database connection. (errors 1 and 2)

Concerning the last error, do you set a custom session id?

Comment: Our problem is that we didn't build this website, and my experience with CK editor is very limited. As the error is pointing to the security.php I've actually removed the line with the mysql_real_escape_string(); 

This causes no warnings just a message: The uploading of files is not working at the moment.

And the credentials have not changed, else the whole website would be empty, CKfinder seems to be the only thing having a problem. I Don't see any files modified after 2014-07-15, over a year ago. In between the CKfinder has worked, because I can see they uploaded messages with images.

Comment: Weird. Any plugins/ addons installed/updated? Any platform updates?

Comment: We choose to go for a fresh install, this works fine without any problem. Still can't explain what was going on. We asked the if there had been an update to the server which to me could be the only thing messing up something that worked before and has not been changed in the code.